# elasticsearch conditional Boost Index time and Query time

Tags: elasticsearch

I have twitter_user_index

I want to boost tweets score in index time

```
If user.verified:
   boost: 10
elif user.follower_count in range (1, 100):
   boost: 1
elif user.follower_count in range (101, 200):
   boost: 2
```

How do I achieve this kind of boosting in index time or in query time (both answers welcome)

Comment: it depends on your query. can you share an example?

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris this is the query that I want to achieve
user.verified == a celebrity account thus highest boost
else boost with followers_count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have  taken an index with below mapping. "user" I have taken as "object type", if your type is "nested" then you need to use nested query, rest structure will be same.

**Mappings:**

```
PUT twitter_user_index 
  {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "user":{
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "verified":{
              "type":"boolean"
            },
            "follower_count":{
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Data:** I have taken three records. 2 users with verified account having less than 100 and more than 100 followers respectively and one user with non verified account having more than 100 followers

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gwiu-HEBZgLhu13ZIerO",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "abc",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 90
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hAiu-HEBZgLhu13Za-qL",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "efg",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 120
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hQiu-HEBZgLhu13ZhOrr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "verified" : false,
            "follower_count" : 120
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query:** I have used a should clause which will not filter out any document, one score matching documents higher. Each clause has its boost to increase relevance.

```
GET twitter_user_index/_search
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "term": {
              "user.verified": {
                "value": true,
                "boost": 10
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "user.follower_count": {
                "gte": 1,
                "lte": 100,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "user.follower_count": {
                "gte": 101,
                "lte": 200,
                "boost": 2
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Result:** In output of query, verified accounts are scored higher than non verified account and accounts with followers in given range are scored higher.

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hAiu-HEBZgLhu13Za-qL",
        "_score" : 6.700036,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "efg",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 120
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gwiu-HEBZgLhu13ZIerO",
        "_score" : 5.700036,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "abc",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 90
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hQiu-HEBZgLhu13ZhOrr",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "verified" : false,
            "follower_count" : 120
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**EDIT1:** Elasticsearch DSL if else blocks cannot be added. We can add additonal should clause that verified:false and range between 1 and 100 then select document applying boost.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user.verified": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "user.verified": {
                    "value": false
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "user.follower_count": {
                    "gte": 1,
                    "lte": 100,
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "user.verified": {
                    "value": false
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "user.follower_count": {
                    "gte": 101,
                    "lte": 200,
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hAiu-HEBZgLhu13Za-qL",
        "_score" : 5.566749,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "efg",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 120
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hgi4-HEBZgLhu13ZW-rY",
        "_score" : 5.566749,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "xyz1",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 150
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gwiu-HEBZgLhu13ZIerO",
        "_score" : 4.566749,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "abc",
            "verified" : true,
            "follower_count" : 90
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter_user_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hQiu-HEBZgLhu13ZhOrr",
        "_score" : 4.4079456,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "verified" : false,
            "follower_count" : 120
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**EDIT3**
Optimized version using filter clause. Filter doesn't calculate score so is faster

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user.verified": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "user.verified": {
                    "value": false
                  }
                }
              }],
              "must":[{
                "range": {
                  "user.follower_count": {
                    "gte": 1,
                    "lte": 100,
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "user.verified": {
                    "value": false
                  }
                }
              }],
              "must":[
              {
                "range": {
                  "user.follower_count": {
                    "gte": 101,
                    "lte": 200,
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your particular example.

Comment: In your particular example.
User {"name" : "efg"}
gets two boost +10 for verified & +1 for follower

I am looking for the conditional clause as mention in Question, in which a document will be boosted based on only 1 criterion

Comment: @KaushikJ I have updated the answer. This will give same score to verified account with different followers, is that ok, or you want different scores based on followers for verified account

Comment: yes your second edit answers my question. Let me know if this is the most optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: @KaushikJ I have optimzed query using filter clause on verfied:false. I don't think it needs to calculate score for this particular part so will be faster. Please compare Edit2 and Edit3 for all your use cases. I think query is already in its simplest form, cannot be reduced further